# Download the HTML code of a website which uses JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to download the html code of a page with
     `wget --load-cookies=cookies.txt`

https://www.strava.com/athletes/3780658#interval?interval=201531&interval_type=week&chart_type=miles&year_offset=0

But I only get the HTML code of the main page of the athlete, I mean, without the HTML code after JavaScript is executed.

I would like to get the HTML of the information like I see in the Firefox browser.

Comment: This is beyond the capabilities of wget. You'll need something that can execute the JavaScript (probably by automating a browser). So start by picking a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casper.js is a scripting language with a headless browser built-in (Phantom.js). http://casperjs.org/

Using that, you can do arbitrary data scraping.
see this example: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#now-let-s-scrape-google